# NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains c++ equivalent

Tags: c++, objective-c, path

on objectiv-c I have the follow method:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

it return the app folders, on emulator:

```
/Users/ademar/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/78A001F6-DDDE-4F6D-B762-8AAF42F1A1E3/Documents
```

I need the same on C++ but I'm not finding, have a similar method on c++?

Comment: I don't believe so.. iOS is mainly an Objective-C API just create an Objective-C++ (.mm) wrapper for it

Comment: @JustinMeiners I need on .cpp class because i go use it on IOS and Android :)

Comment: I have been looking for a CoreFoundation equivalent, which is the only way you could do it from C++, however I cannot find one.  You'll have to get the caller of your library (or whatever you're writing) to tell you such things.

Comment: @trojanfoe so sad :(, but i'll go create a static class on obj-c to send this info and on android the same with java, not is the best way but if don't have equivalent methods. tks a lot.

Comment: @ademar111190 its called abstraction, write one set of code for android and one set for ios. Than have one function you call that picks which to use. There is not going to be some magic function that gives it to you on both.

Comment: @JustinMeiners I'll go do it, thanks, only in curiosity do you know some howto for make this?

Comment: @ademar111190 I am not familar with the Android C++ API but I am guessing it would provide a similar function to get the documents directory. char* GetDoscDir () { if (android) { GetDocsDirAndroid() } else if (iOS) { GetDocsDirPhone() }

Comment: GetDocsDirAnroid and GetDocsDirPhone would be your own functions. GetDocsDiriPhone would be in a .mm and call NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains and convert it to a C string the GetDocsDirAndroid would call whatever the android equivalent was and do the same

Comment: @JustinMeiners perfect, I'll go do it, later i post here the code, thanks a lot!

Comment: @ademar111190 Did you make the code? I'm with the same problem. I need  to do exactly what you described at your question. Cheers.

Comment: @R31n4ld0_ unfortunately not found a way to do this, what I did was create a class dependancySystem and it added a method to return the path :/